# What symbol can be used in front of a URL ?

Tags: symbols, characters

When you typeset an email address, you can put a "@" or a letter symbol in front of it. In the same fashion, what symbol can be used in front of a URL?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is the `\Mundus` command from the `marvosym` package. It inserts a world globe.

**EDIT:** Better example!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\Mundus~\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** A screenshot! `=P`

[image: Globe]

I think it suits the occasion. `=)`

**UPDATE:** Here's an update based on Martin Scharrer's idea. I got [this globe](http://thenounproject.com/site_media/svg/248.svg) from [The Noun Project](http://thenounproject.com/) and converted to a `PDF` file named **globe.pdf** (also available [here](http://www.dc.ufscar.br/~paulo_cereda/latex/globe.pdf)). Then:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}

\newcommand*\myglobe{%
% as suggested by Martin ;-)
\includegraphics[height=1.6ex]{globe.pdf}}

\begin{document}

\Mundus~\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}

\myglobe~\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}

\end{document}
```

The new output:

[image: Output]

Comment: I had found this one already, it's indeed a good one :-)

Comment: Examples are also here in [LaTeX Coolness @The Telarah Times](http://jamesmcdonald.id.au/it-tips/latex-coolness) post: [\Mundus PDF](http://jamesmcdonald.id.au/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/mundus.pdf). Personally I don't like it, as it is too filled, which makes it a bit vague.

Comment: @przemoc: I noticed that. `=(` When used on a tiny font, this symbol almost looks like a black dot.

Comment: @Raphink: Paulo and me recently had a look on http://thenounproject.com after Seamus talked about it. It has a lot of icons like that, see e.g. http://thenounproject.com/en-us/category/tech-communication/. They are SVG graphics which can be converted to PDF (e.g. `inkscape --export-pdf file.pdf file.svg`) and included as images. We are working on a package providing this symbols.

Comment: Maybe: http://thenounproject.com/site_media/svg/116.svg

Comment: @Martin: Awesome idea!

Comment: I would simply use `height=1.6ex` (or similar value in `ex`) so that the icons scales with the font size.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for the improvement, Martin!

Comment: I've tried the world symbol, and it's true that it doesn't look very serious in a "dead serious publication" ;-) Maybe I should stick to just the URL in books, and use this more like in my CV ;-)

Comment: The globe looks quite good. But you should be aware that it shows a specific part of the world (in this case africa, europe, asia) and has specific center. Depending on the context where you use such a globe it can be viewed as a political statement which part of the world is more important to you. I wouldn't e.g. use it in a job application for a job in amerika or as a logo for a global organisation.

Comment: @Ulrike: Hm now that you mentioned, the globe has _really_ an specific center. To avoid such political or geographical interpretations, I'd probably stick with the second globe, with is stylized and has no margins for comments. `=)`

Comment: It would be nice though when the icon itself would be clickable and when the icon would be appended automatically by a macro, too.

Comment: @Martin: May I ask, is the package containing the symbols from the Noun Project completed, or at least still underway?

Answer (score 12):

I use the [external link icon from fontawesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/external-link/).

[image]

There is a [LaTeX package for LuaTeX/XeTeX to use fontawesome](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) and an [non-official version for PDFTeX](https://github.com/texcode/fontawesome/tree/pdftex). An example of its usage can be found in the [PDF version of the new German FAQ](http://ctan.org/pkg/detexfaq):

[image]

I like it because IMO it's not obtrusive, compared to the "world" icons.

Comment: it's called `\faExternalLink` in `\usepackage{fontawesome}`

Answer (score 7):

Here is my try at bringing more readable globe to LaTeX. It is quite inaccurate, but IMO it's acceptable for non utterly dead serious publications. :)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,landscape,margin=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,setspace,url}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0pt
\doublespacing
\newcommand\globe{%
\hspace{0.25em}%
\tikz
%% Work based on the:
%% Globe icon from Brightmix iconset
%% by Brightmix licensed under WTFPL
%% http://www.iconfinder.com/browse/iconset/brightmix/
%% http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/brightmix/128/monotone_earth_world_transparent.png
%%
%% Traced and simplified in Inkscape, exported using inkscape2tikz.
%% Simplification and adjustment in Vim by Przemoc.
\path [y=0.009ex,x=0.009ex,yscale=-1,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,fill]
    (90,90) circle (90)%
    (99,167) .. controls (128,164) and (155,142) ..
    (164,114) .. controls (166,107) and (170,96) ..
    (166,90) .. controls (160,91) and (159,109) ..
    (156,97) .. controls (155,87) and (142,82) ..
    (133,81) .. controls (131,89) and (146,83) ..
    (141,91) .. controls (136,97) and (125,103) ..
    (123,91) .. controls (123,87) and (115,80) ..
    (120,88) .. controls (121,94) and (124,107) ..
    (132,101) .. controls (137,110) and (120,115) ..
    (123,125) .. controls (119,133) and (112,141) ..
    (104,145) .. controls (92,148) and (91,132) ..
    (91,124) .. controls (91,115) and (87,106) ..
    (78,110) .. controls (72,112) and (67,111) ..
    (64,106) .. controls (60,103) and (58,99) ..
    (59,93) .. controls (58,83) and (67,77) ..
    (71,70) .. controls (63,68) and (69,57) ..
    (75,60) .. controls (70,51) and (83,49) ..
    (88,44) .. controls (95,46) and (108,42) ..
    (101,34) .. controls (97,26) and (100,47) ..
    (92,41) .. controls (88,39) and (80,37) ..
    (87,32) .. controls (93,26) and (103,29) ..
    (111,29) .. controls (118,28) and (132,30) ..
    (134,27) .. controls (127,19) and (116,16) ..
    (105,13) .. controls (91,10) and (76,11) ..
    (62,17) .. controls (55,20) and (43,22) ..
    (44,31) .. controls (47,38) and (37,50) ..
    (33,49) .. controls (32,43) and (28,38) ..
    (25,46) .. controls (18,54) and (31,66) ..
    (20,72) .. controls (10,78) and (10,91) ..
    (12,101) .. controls (14,112) and (26,115) ..
    (30,125) .. controls (37,130) and (47,134) ..
    (39,143) .. controls (32,149) and (47,154) ..
    (51,158) .. controls (65,165) and (83,170) ..
    (99,167) --
    cycle
    (124,138) .. controls (119,132) and (136,122) ..
    (129,133) .. controls (128,134) and (128,139) ..
    (124,138) --
    cycle
    (73,42) .. controls (63,39) and (81,27) ..
    (80,39) .. controls (80,41) and (75,44) ..
    (73,42) --
    cycle
    (100,77) .. controls (105,74) and (121,81) ..
    (115,72) .. controls (111,71) and (106,63) .. 
    (103,69) .. controls (99,66) and (98,56) .. 
    (93,60) .. controls (97,61) and (98,70) .. 
    (93,64) .. controls (90,52) and (70,71) .. 
    (81,70) .. controls (91,64) and (93,82) ..
    (100,77) --
    cycle
    (136,67) .. controls (138,62) and (133,52) ..
    (129,61) .. controls (131,63) and (133,77) ..
    (136,67) --
    cycle
    (123,63) .. controls (122,55) and (104,57) ..
    (112,64) .. controls (116,65) and (120,66) ..
    (123,63) --
    cycle;%
\hspace{0.25em}%
}
\newcommand\texsxurl{URL \globe\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}}
\begin{document}
\par\tiny\texsxurl
\par\scriptsize\texsxurl
\par\footnotesize\texsxurl
\par\small\texsxurl
\par\normalsize\texsxurl
\par\large\texsxurl
\par\Large\texsxurl
\par\LARGE\texsxurl
\par\huge\texsxurl
\par\Huge\texsxurl
\par\fontsize{32}{36}\selectfont\texsxurl
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Some people are crazier than me! :P

Comment: Nice, the border is thicker than in the marvosym version, and overall it's cuter. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As Paulo Cereda mentions, you can use Mundus.

I would like to add that you can use `\href` to display text, instead of the url, like a placholder. Like this:

```
\Mundus~\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{stackexchange}
```

So full usable code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\Mundus~\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{stackexchange}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Just a few tips: you can mark up code by indenting it with 4 spaces, or by selecting it and clicking `{}`, or by hitting Ctr+K. Also, to use `\href` you need the `hyperref` package, not only `url`. And finally, the OP asked for the "symbol", not the link, and the symbol was, as you mentioned, covered by Paulo Cereda, so your answer is more fit to a comment, in this case. But since you don't have the reputation (yet :) to leave a comment, I think it's fine +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something and found [this super helpful list](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) of LaTeX symbols online. Here's something from the `fontawesome` package that you may find relevant for links: [image: link_latex]