# external-link symbol needed for pdfLaTex compiler

Tags: pdftex, symbols, fontawesome

I am looking for the package which can support external-link symbol for pdfLatex format. I don't want to use XeLatex or LuaLatex because I get errors, so I want to stick with pdfLatex format. However in this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22536/what-symbol-can-be-used-in-front-of-a-url) answered by a user named 'topskip' gives a link for non-official pdfTex version for fontawesome package. So this takes me [here](https://github.com/texcode/fontawesome/tree/pdftex). But now I can't download any pdfTex version package from this link. I can't understand how to include 'fontawesome' package for pdftex/pdflatex compiler. Can someone direct me to get this external-link symbol in pdfLatex.

In order to see the external-link symbol run this code in xeLaTex or luaLaTex:

```
    % Compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

% Redefinition, symbol included in link:
\let\orighref\href
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{\orighref{#1}{#2\,\faExternalLink}}

\begin{document}
\href{http://example.com}{example web site}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome?lang=en

Comment: Could you please post an image of the "external-link symbol"?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I am aware of that link. But the point of my question is to find, if there is way to get this symbol when I run with pdfLatex and not xeLatex or luaLatex

Comment: You don't need xaLatex or luaLatex.  I just tested it to make sure.  The warring is that IF YOU USE xaLatex or luaLatex you will also need fontspec.  If you use pdfLatex, all you need is \usepackage{fontawesome}.