# How to cite a paper in the title page of beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, texmaker

I'm supposed to give a beamer presentation based on a paper and I need to cite that on the title page. How do I cite the reference on the title page? I have options such as "\title{}", "\date{}", $"\institute{}"$ but I don't have anything such as "\journal{}". Please help me.

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404604/making-it-clear-that-colored-text-is-a-link-in-beamer-presentation/404626#404626) is an example that cites a paper on the title page.

Comment: @marmot I seems quite complicated for a beginner like me.

Answer (score 2):

You can cite your paper by putting the citation below the `\titlepage` command. Here is an example. If you do not use inspire, replace `\Cite` by `\cite`.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage[round,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Witten:1985xb,
     author    = "Witten, Edward",
     title     = "DIMENSIONAL REDUCTION OF SUPERSTRING MODELS",
     journal   = "Phys. Lett.",
     volume    = "B155",
     year      = "1985",
     pages     = "151",
     SLACcitation  = "%%CITATION = PHLTA,B155,151;%%"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\Cite}[1]{%
\href{http://inspirehep.net/search?p=#1}{\citet*{#1}}
}

\title{\Large Citing on a beamer titlepage} %
\author{An anonymous marmot}

\date{yesterday}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\titlepage

Just put your citation here \Cite{Witten:1985xb}

The point is that you may put anything below the \texttt{titlepage} command.

Don't forget to run \texttt{bibtex}

\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\appendix

\section{Appendix}

\subsection{References}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
\def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT** If you want to have the references on the title page, use

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage[round,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Witten:1985xb,
     author    = "Witten, Edward",
     title     = "DIMENSIONAL REDUCTION OF SUPERSTRING MODELS",
     journal   = "Phys. Lett.",
     volume    = "B155",
     year      = "1985",
     pages     = "151",
     SLACcitation  = "%%CITATION = PHLTA,B155,151;%%"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\Cite}[1]{%
\href{http://inspirehep.net/search?p=#1}{\citet*{#1}}
}

\title{\Large Citing on a beamer titlepage} %
\author{An anonymous marmot}

\date{yesterday}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\titlepage

Just put your citation here \Cite{Witten:1985xb}

The point is that you may put anything below the \texttt{titlepage} command.

Don't forget to run \texttt{bibtex}

\def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
```

Of course, if you have several references, they might not fit on the title page, but this is a separate issue.

Comment: I want to display the journal reference on the title page. @marmot

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `\fullcite` command from biblatex could help?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein,
author = {Einstein, A.},
title = {Die Grundlage der allgemeinen Relativit\"atstheorie},
journal = {Annalen der Physik},
volume = {354},
number = {7},
pages = {769--822},
year = {1916}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\title[Paper summary]{Paper summary: \fullcite{einstein}}
\author{name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]